# How to map caps lock to ESC in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

How to set up AutoHotkey so that when I press the Caps Lock, it will instead send the ESC key to the computer?

Comment: Try `Capslock::Send {ESC}`

Answer (score 36):

Mapping Caps Lock key to ESC key can be done as:

```
Capslock::Esc
```

Using this format, you can easily map Caps Lock to any key, for example, the enter key:

```
Capslock::Enter
```

Comment: For completeness, since escape key is mapped to caps lock, I enable the escape to be the caps lock key.
`Esc::Capslock`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to also map Esc to Capslock at the same time, do this:

```
$Capslock::Esc
$Esc::Capslock
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Window Spy** or try `F12:keyhistory` to viewer a key code

[image: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm]

**Keymapping:**

`Capslock::MsgBox,,,test1`

**VK**

`vk14::MsgBox,,,test2`

**SC**

`sc03A::MsgBox,,,test13`

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Look:
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm